# Product Bulk Upload

Tags: magento-1.9, product, upload

Please suggest me the alternative product bulk upload methods if any rather than the default import and data profile import method. Was looking for it and got to know about AvS Fast Simple Import. How efficient is AvS Fast Simple Import?

Answer (score 1):

We often use the [MAGMI importer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/)

it is extremely fast and powerful.